# Change content on the amount of posts in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

Hello I want to change the content on the amount of posts so if the foreach loop got only 2 posts it should say 2. But it is not working?

```
<?php if (!empty($iconMenu)) { ?>
<nav class="menu-top">
<?php $i = 0; 
foreach($iconMenu as $icon) {
    $page = Website::getActiveTreeBranch($icon['link']);
    if ($page !== false) {
        $i++;

        if($i=1){ ?>
        1 
        <?php  } ?>

        <?php if($i=2){ ?>
        2 
        <?php  } ?>   

    <?php  }} ?>
<?php } ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why do you close the php tag in the if? Keep it open and use echo "1";. It will make the code cleaner and easier to read in my opinion

Comment: It is still not working, and there should be a huge list of divs in there so echo would make it not cleaner imo.

Comment: What?? So because you add divs you think oh f%$# this, it's so messy I might aswell add the php tags too? That does not make any sense at all.

Comment: You have not given us enough information to solve the problem. You show us a code with 1 and 2 and now talk about 3. (In the comments below). Ok.. a wild guess. If you add if ($i == 3) then maybe you get 3 too. But I don't know because we don't have the same code or information as you do, so we can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Typo:

`=` is assignment operator and `==` is equality check operator.

Change code:

```
if($i=1){ ?>
1 
<?php  } ?>
<?php if($i=2){ ?>
```

To

```
if ($i == 1) {
 echo '1' 
}
if($i == 2) {
```

So, the final (cleaned up code):

```
<?php
if (! empty($iconMenu)) {
    echo '<nav class="menu-top">';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($iconMenu as $icon) {
        $page = Website::getActiveTreeBranch($icon['link']);
        if ($page !== false) {
            $i++;
            if ($i == 1) {
                echo '1';
            }
            if ($i == 2) {
                echo '2 ';
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '</nav>';
?>
```

Comment: You might suggest getting rid of all those `<?php` and `?>` which make the code almost unreadable and definitely more difficult to debug, and using a simple `echo`

Comment: You might need to show him all the code to make it obvious what you have done

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks. I have updated my answer. You are welcome.

Comment: I am not using echo on purpose:) But it is still not working. I have 3 posts in it and it still shows 1 2

Comment: What???!! On purpose... ok, now I have heard it all :-)  maybe you get 1 and 2 because you loop through the code and add one to i each time?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not for the question but to help him how to use the php tag.

```
<?php $i = 0; 
foreach($iconMenu as $icon) {
$page = Website::getActiveTreeBranch($icon['link']);
if ($page !== false) {
    $i++;

    if($i==1){
      Echo "1"; 
    }

    if($i==2){ 
      echo "2"; 
    }   

  }}
 } ?>
</nav>
```

I have not double checked if there is a correct number of { and } as I'm typing on my phone.

EDIT: I forgot to edit the thing that was wrong if =

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I had to use [Count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) instead.